Not able to click outside of the ImmersiveView in VisionPro
I'm trying to build a simple immersive app, but the problem is that I'm not able to interact with the elements of the ContentView once the ImmersiveView is present and active.
Here's my code:
//App.swift
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

@main
struct App: App {
    @StateObject private var appModel = AppModel()

    var body: some SwiftUI.Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(appModel)
        }
        .windowStyle(.volumetric)

        ImmersiveSpace(id: appModel.immersiveSpaceID) {
            ImmersiveView()
                .environmentObject(appModel)
        }
        .immersionStyle(selection: .constant(.mixed), in: .mixed)

        .handlesExternalEvents(matching: [SharedActivity.activityIdentifier])
    }
}

//
//  ContentView.swift
//

import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import RealityKitContent
import GroupActivities

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var appModel: AppModel
    @State private var groupStateObserver: Task<Void, Never>?
    @State private var isLoading = true
    @State private var loadingProgress: Double = 0.0

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            // Main Content
            if !isLoading {
                MainView()
                    .task {
                        groupStateObserver = Task {
                            for await groupSession in SharedActivity.sessions() {
                                appModel.configureGroupSession(groupSession)
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
            
            // Loading Screen
            if isLoading {
                LoadingView(progress: $loadingProgress)
                    .transition(.opacity)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            // Simulate loading progress
            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5)) {
                simulateLoading()
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func simulateLoading() {
        // Simulate loading steps
        let totalSteps = 5
        for step in 1...totalSteps {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(step) * 0.5) {
                withAnimation {
                    loadingProgress = Double(step) / Double(totalSteps)
                    if step == totalSteps {
                        withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 0.5)) {
                            isLoading = false
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
        .environmentObject(AppModel())
}

//
//  ImmersiveView.swift
//

import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ImmersiveView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appModel: AppModel
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ImmersiveViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ImmersiveContentView(viewModel: viewModel)
            .onAppear { appModel.immersiveSpaceState = .open }
            .onDisappear { appModel.immersiveSpaceState = .closed }
    }
} 

//
//  ImmersiveContentView.swift
//

import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import RealityKitContent

struct ImmersiveContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ImmersiveViewModel
    @State private var headAnchor = AnchorEntity(.head)
    
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            guard let scene = try? await Entity(named: "ImmersiveScene", in: realityKitContentBundle) else {
                print("Failed to load ImmersiveScene")
                return
            }
            
            content.add(scene)
            viewModel.currentEntity = scene
        }
        .gesture(
            SpatialTapGesture()
                .onEnded { _ in
                    // Handle general taps in the space
                    print("Tapped in immersive space")
                }
        )
        
        // Add controls as an overlay that doesn't block interactions
        .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
            ImmersiveControlsView(viewModel: viewModel)
                .allowsHitTesting(true) // Explicitly allow hit testing on controls
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ImmersiveContentView(viewModel: ImmersiveViewModel())
} 

I'm not sure why the click is not happening in the ContentView. I'm not even able to drag the window around when the ImmersiveView is active.

It could be a collisions thing in your scene, if you inspect collision elements are they too big?
